# rvest returning NA

Tags: r, rvest

I am using "rvest" for web scraping but i am unable to extract the price for the model from page :-
https://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-z-force-droid-edition
. I need to extract "$720.00" from the page. My code is :-

```
library(rvest)

data<-read_html("https://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-z-force-droid-edition")

price<-data%>%
html_nodes(".price-amount")%>%
html_text()
print(price)
```

I keep getting character(0) for the price.

Please help.

Comment: That site uses javascript to render the page (and to insert the prices into the page). To see what rvest downloads do `download.file("<yoururl>", "output.html")` and look at `output.html` in an editor. You'll see the prices are missing; there are some placeholder `<span>`s that get filled with the price. In order to scrape sites like that you will have to use a headless browser such as PhantomJS. Perhaps https://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-javascript-rendered-sites/ is of use.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give an example by doing this for the above mentioned site?

Comment: I don't have any experience with PhantomJS, so I can't help you there (that is also the reason I didn't write an answer). Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Thank you.

Comment: Search around for some tutorials on using `RSelenium`, which is one possible interface to phantomJS (and other browsers).

Answer (score 1):

```
url<-"https://www.motorola.com/us/js/motorola_blc_catalog/price/1281"
page<-html_session(url)
text<-XML::xmlToList(XML::xmlParse(httr::content(page$response)$price))
price<-text$tbody$tr$td$span$text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rvest with RSelenium and seleniumPipes. Make sure to download phantomJS and put .exe file in current R working directory. See [my other answser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655215/scraping-website-in-r/48660845#48660845) for details.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium) # start a server with utility function
library(seleniumPipes)
#start server
rD <- rsDriver (browser = 'chrome',chromever = "latest",port = 4445L)
#open browser
remDr <- remoteDr(browserName = "chrome",port = 4445L)
web_url <- "https://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-z-force-droid-edition"

remDr %>% go(web_url)
price <- remDr %>% getPageSource() %>% html_nodes(".price-amount") %>% html_text()

print(price)    
[1] "$30.00/mo" "$720.00"   "$720.00" 

remDr %>% deleteSession() # delete session
rD[["server"]]$stop() # close server
```

In short, You need to use a headless browser to render javascript generated values. After that, you can use rvest as usual.