# Scraping website in R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape the name, city, state, email, etc of professionals from this website http://www.napo.net/search/newsearch.asp using rvest, but I can't seem to get the CSS selectors using selector gadget and the e-mails are protected with JavaScript.

I have checked the forums and haven't seen any issue like this.

Comment: member details on that search result page appears through mouseover. There seems to be a link to those individual member detail pages. What about if you go to each one of those pages and scrape it from there? You can scrape the link to the id from each member through the id 'SearchResultsGrid'

Comment: You're spot on about the individual member pages, but I can't scrape the links to their profiles. I used 'SearchResultsGrid' as the selector in 'html_nodes' (rvest package) and it returned an empty list

Comment: the actual search results page is embedded to your posted link using iframe element. I am posting the code below to get the member list using actual search results link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses seleniumPipes and RSelenium package. You should also download phantomjs ,unzip it and put .exe file in in your R working directory.
This method uses a headless browser(phantomjs) which simulates user behavior. It can read javascript generated values.

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium) # start a server with utility function
library(seleniumPipes)
rD <- rsDriver (browser = 'chrome',chromever = "latest",port = 4444L)
#open browser
remDr <- remoteDr(browserName = "chrome")

main_page_url <- "http://www.napo.net/search/newsearch.asp"
#go to home page
remDr %>% go(main_page_url)
#switch to iframe
remDr %>% switchToFrame(Id = "SearchResultsFrame")
#get all relative path
relative_path <- remDr %>% getPageSource() %>% html_nodes(".lineitem a[href]") %>% html_attr("href")
#all individual urls:
full_paths <- paste0("http://www.napo.net",relative_path)
#scrape email from each page
email_address <- list()
#Retrieve email adress from the first three results
for(i in seq_along(full_paths[1:3])){
    remDr %>% go(full_paths[i])
    email_adress <- remDr %>% getPageSource()  %>% html_nodes('a[href^="mailto"]') %>% html_text()
    temp_list <- list(email = email_adress)
    email_address <- c(email_address,temp_list)
    Sys.sleep(3)
}
#display result
email_address[1]
    $email
[1] "marla@123organize.com"
```

Above are all for page one, if you want to turn to page two:

```
remDr %>% go(main_page_url)
remDr %>% switchToFrame(Id = "SearchResultsFrame")
#click on page two on iframe to turn to page 2:
remDr %>% findElement(using = "css selector",value = ".DotNetPager a:nth-child(2)") %>% elementClick()
#get relative and full path again
relative_path <- remDr %>% getPageSource() %>% html_nodes(".lineitem a[href]") %>% html_attr("href")
full_paths <- paste0("http://www.napo.net",relative_path)
#And you can do the for loop again
for(i in seq_along(full_paths[1:3])){
    remDr %>% go(full_paths[i])
    email_adress <- remDr %>% getPageSource()  %>% html_nodes('a[href^="mailto"]') %>% html_text()
    temp_list <- list(email = email_adress)
    email_address <- c(email_address,temp_list)
    Sys.sleep(3)
}
#display result[6]
$email
[1] "lynette@itssimplyplaced.com"

email_address
#You can also do a loop to scrape all pages
#-----
#delete session and close server
remDr %>% deleteSession()
rD[["server"]]$stop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Please for future problems, may I know how you got the css selector for the 'findElement' function as well as that used to extract the email and relative paths

Comment: Sure, if you search for key words in source code, you will find this line writes the email address `document.write('&lt;a href="mailto:'+ strEmail + '"&gt;'+ strEmail + '&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;');` , So the syntax to find href that start with "mailto" is 'a[href^="mailto"]'. By using `remDr %>% getPageSource()`, all javascript generated values are automatically rendered(e.g. ``<a href="mailto:marla@123organize.com">marla@123organize.com</a>``). so you can find it like in normal HTML file.

Comment: Also, you can use [CSS selector gadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) as usual, since the javascript generated values are already rendered. This CSS selector also works: "#SpContent_Container a:nth-child(6)"  `[1] <a href="mailto:marla@123organize.com">marla@123organize.com</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it in 2 steps.

1.to get the link to the embedded search result pages:

```
require(rvest)
require(magrittr)
yourlink <- "http://www.napo.net/search/newsearch.asp"
linktoresult <- yourlink %>% read_html() %>%
                html_nodes("iframe") %>% extract(1) %>%
                html_attr("src")

# /searchserver/people.aspx?id=FE0436D0-08ED-4763-8588-09112794521D&cdbid=&canconnect=0&canmessage=0&map=True&toggle=False&hhSearchTerms=
```

2.scrape from the actual search result page:

```
pagelink <- paste0("http://www.napo.net", linktoresult)
# "http://www.napo.net/searchserver/people.aspx?id=FE0436D0-08ED-4763-8588-09112794521D&cdbid=&canconnect=0&canmessage=0&map=True&toggle=False&hhSearchTerms="

yourresult <- pagelink %>% read_html() %>%
              html_nodes("#SearchResultsGrid>.lineitem") %>%
              html_nodes("a") %>% 
              html_attr("href")
#/members/?id=42241027
#NA
#/members/?id=46636113
#/members/?id=37474237
#/members/?id=39530420
#...
```